# Is it possible to prevent database files from being deleted/modified externally without having it opened in c#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, file

**The situation:**

I'm currently debugging code from my predecessor which handles sqlite databases (.db3 file format). 
In the software you can load one or several databases. General Information (getting all table names, getting all column names, etc) on these databases is handled directly from the files, but for actual data information the databases are copied to a in-memory database where data is queried from. 
So after the initial information is gathered and all data is saved to the memory database, the actual files are not used anymore.

However, they are still represented on the GUI and referenced, if the user adds/deletes databases from the list.

**The problem:**

All of this leads to the following problem: If a user modifies/deletes the file of a loaded database (which is possible, because we don't have an open connection to the files), the internal database pool of the software differs from the actual file list. As an effect, we have undefined behavior in such a case, as soon as the list of used databases is updated.

**possible solutions(?)**

- Probably the best thing to do, would be to rework the complete code and keep everything within the memory-database (GUI representation, data, database information,...). In this case I wouldn't need to worry about the files at all. However this would mean a major rework and...no time for that^^
- Just open a sqlite-connections to all files and leave them open, as long as the respective in-memory database is listed as 'used'(not really a good option in my opinion).
- Find a way to prevent files from being deleted/modified without having them opened. I'm not sure if/how that would be possible, what I have read so far is the one would need to change accessibility rights for the files programmatically which leads to several issues concerning user-rights in windows...

**The question:**
Is there another way/suggestion for this issue? For me the best/easiest approach would be to find a way to just prevent a list of files from being modified. So far I haven't found a good solution for that approach.

Comment: Ok, after a meeting with the boss we will rework the code. However, I would still be interested if it is possible to lock files as described in the question.

Comment: Why don't you just rename the database file and its extention when you are done with it? That way anything else trying to access it will report errors since it can't find the file. When you need it again in your code, rename it back to what it is supposed to be and use it accordingly.

Comment: I'm actually talking about users themselves deleting and changing the files manually  in Windows Explorer.

Comment: You can't. Why would users be modifying database files in windows explorer? What is in theses databases?

Comment: The databases contain different testdata...the issue came up, when a user deleted the database from a failed test while the software was still open with the respective db loaded. The software should either handle the missing file correctly or prevent the user from being able to delete the file while the software still uses it.

Comment: The thing is, the software isn't still using it. It closed the connection to it and now the file can be deleted. If you keep the connection open and try to delete the file, windows will prevent you to and notify you that the file is in use.

Comment: I know. As it stands now, I will refactor the code to handle these things correctly. I was just curious, if locking files would have been possible. So the answer seems to be NO - if you write it as answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Why not keep the code, create another connection to the file, just to keep it locked while you are still using it's data? You can dispose of the connection once you are done with the data. This will allow you to refactor the existing code without time pressure.

Comment: As far as I understand this is the same thing as I describe in the second point of possible solutions in the OP. As you mention in the answer, this is a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Maybe this will be of interest to you, for use with PInvoke: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping a connection open to a SQLite database file will prevent Windows from deleting it.

A poor but quick solution could be to allow the original code to read the file to memory, then to grab a new connection to the file. You can keep this connection open without doing anything with it, preventing it from being deleted. Once the user of the application is done using that dataset, you dispose of the connection, allowing the file to be deleted again.

I would *not* recommend this - it's a dirty fix. It may however give you more time to properly refactor the code.